# Select nested xml element where nested tag is the same name using clojure.data.zip

Tags: xml, clojure, zipper

I have a bit of XML that I'm wrangling using `clojure.data.zip.xml`. That XML has elements with the same name as nested elements:

```
<things>
  <thing>
    <thing>Want this</thing>
    <thingattr>...but not this</thingattr>
  </thing>
  <thing>
    <thing>Select this</thing>
    <thingattr>...again, not this</thingattr>
  </thing>
</things>
```

However, accessing the inner element seems to be beyond my reach with the `xml->` function in clojure.data.zip.xml. If, however, the nested element does not share the same name as the parent, all works as expected:

```
(ns xmlzip.core
  (:require [clojure.xml :as xml]
            [clojure.zip]
            [clojure.data.zip.xml :as z])
  (:gen-class))

(defn parse [s]
  (clojure.xml/parse
   (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream. (.getBytes s))))

(def example1 (clojure.zip/xml-zip (parse "
<things>
  <thing>
    <thing>Want this</thing>
    <thingattr>...but not this</thingattr>
  </thing>
  <thing>
    <thing>Select this</thing>
    <thingattr>...again, not this</thingattr>
  </thing>
</things>
")))

(def example2 (clojure.zip/xml-zip (parse "
<things>
  <thing>
    <subthing>Want this</subthing>
    <thingattr>...but not this</thingattr>
  </thing>
  <thing>
    <subthing>Select this</subthing>
    <thingattr>...again, not this</thingattr>
  </thing>
</things>
")))


(z/xml-> example2 :thing :subthing z/text)
;; ("Want this" "Select this") ;hooray!

(z/xml-> example1 :thing :thing z/text)
;; ("Want this...but not this" "Select this...again, not this") ;boo, hiss.
```

I suspect that this may be an unaddressed case in `clojure.data.zip.xml`, but I am hoping that someone can show me the proper usage if I am simply misunderstanding how to use the library.

Comment: This looks like a good case to post to the clojure mailing list:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/clojure

Comment: Thank you, I've gone ahead and posted there (pending moderation). This kind of feels like a bug to me, but my first intuition is that I am just using it wrong. Hopefully mailing list folks can steer me in the right direction.

Comment: For anybody stumbling upon this, bug is https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/DZIP-6, please vote for it (on the "Vote" button on the top right, not as a "me too" comment).